# isset in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, isset

I want check if there is class `.required_selectbox` in html code run function `required_selectbox()` and if there is class `.required` in html code run function `required_valid()`, after submit, how is it?

```
function required_valid() {
    $('.required').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            //var cssObj=;
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
            result = true;
        }
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        })
    });
    return result;
}

function required_selectbox() {
    $('.required_selectbox').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            //var cssObj=;
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        } else {
            result = true;
        }

    });
    return result;
}
$('.submit').submit(function () {
    //alert('hello');
    var passed = true;
    passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
    passed = required_valid() && passed;
    if (!passed) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the `var` keyword, which is missing where you assign to the `result` variable several times in your code.  Always declare your variables in the correct scope or they will leak into the global scope.

Comment: Your use of the `result` variable doesn't make any sense. It's set within a loop. What is the return value of `required_selectbox` supposed to represent? Whether _all_ the selectboxes are valie, or whether _any_ select boxes are valid?

Comment: try using ( !! ) double not operator for it, search to figure out some solution using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to run those functions *even if the elements aren't there*.  Because no elements would be found, the calls to `each()` would do nothing, so all that's needed is to have the `result` variable set to `true` by default:

```
function required_selectbox() {
    var result = true;  // <--- 
    $('.required_selectbox').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            //var cssObj=;
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        } else {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Also, it looks like you probably don't want the `else` statement in there so you might want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure hat you want, but -

```
 $('.required_selectbox').length
```

would let you know if there were any elements of class `.required_selectbox` in your document. You could then do a similiar thing for `required_valid`

Answer (score 0):

```
function required_valid() {
    var required = $('.required');
    required.css("background", "#FFFFEC");

    //Find any empty elements, and add the red style
    var empty = required.filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == '';
    });
    empty.css("background", "#ffc4c4");

    //Did we find any empty elements?
    return empty.length > 0;
}

function required_selectbox() {
    var required = $('.required_selectbox');
    required.css("background", "#FFFFEC");

    //Find any empty elements, and add the red style
    var empty = required.filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == '';
    });
    empty.css("background", "#ffc4c4");

    //Did we find any empty elements?
    return empty.length > 0;
}

$('.submit').submit(function() {
    return required_selectbox() && required_valid();
});
```